# Static variable initialization for template specialization in header

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods, template-specialization, static-variables

There is a C++ header library, but at some point there has been added template specialization (right in the header).
Everything was good, until required link together two files which used this library. Of course, there was a linker error.
The problem is that the library's classes use static variables. They are initialized for template specialization directly in the header file.

The question is: is it possible to initialize a static variable in the header file for the template specialization and somehow avoid linking error?
(Something like add inline keyword for template class method specialization with similar linking problem.)

Any ideas are welcome (including dirty tricks etc).

Some code example:

*lib.hpp:*

```
template <typename T>
struct LibClass
{
    static const int variable;
    static void f()
    {
        // use variable
    }
};

typedef LibClass<int> IntLibClass;
template <> const int IntLibClass::variable = 0;

typedef LibClass<double> DoubleLibClass;
template <> const int DoubleLibClass::variable = 1;
```

*A.cpp:*

```
#include "lib.hpp"

void g()
{
    IntLibClass a;
    a.f();
}
```

*B.cpp:*

```
#include "lib.hpp"

void h()
{
    DoubleLibClass b;
    b.f();
}

int main()
{
     h();
}
```

And I want link A and B together.

```
g++ A.cpp B.cpp
```

Comment: An explicit specialization of a class template is much like a class. You could try a partial specialization.

Comment: Instead of using a static variable, you could use a static function that returns a reference (is an interface change, though). The problem AFAIK is not the initialization, but the *definition* of the variable.

Comment: If you can initialize the static member inline (in the class definition) it is only available as a compile-time constant and will not trigger linking issues. Either by actually specializing the entire class or by making the desired int value a second template parameter.

Comment: @dyp There is not a full specialization of a class template, there is a full specialization of a class template member.

Comment: @Constructor Oh, you're right, of course. But the issue is the same: an explicit specialization is not a template. An explicit specialization of a static data member of a class template is much like a .. static data member of a class.

Comment: @dyp Yes, I think your analogies are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add to your project additional file `lib.cpp` with the following contents:

```
#include "lib.hpp"

template <> const int IntLibClass::variable = 0;

template <> const int DoubleLibClass::variable = 1;
```

And change your `lib.hpp` file in the following way (remove initialization):

```
typedef LibClass<int> IntLibClass;
template <> const int IntLibClass::variable;

typedef LibClass<double> DoubleLibClass;
template <> const int DoubleLibClass::variable;
```

As [**Johannes Schaub - litb**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) noted in comments this solution implies no initialization of a static variable in the header file (as it was required in the question), so the variable value can not be used in constant expressions (outside of `lib.cpp` file).

But this solution is appropriate for the code snippets which are given in the question.

Comment: This does not "initialize a static variable in the header file", therefor you cannot use the variable value in constant expressions.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Thank you for your valuable comment. Yes, you are right, this solution does not include initialization of a static variable in the header file. But it is useful for the code which is given in the question. And nothing about using of a static variable in constant expressions outside of `lib.hpp` file was in the question.